# Where to place my imports in a multi-module project?

Tags: python, python-import

Needless to say, but the pet project I use to learn-by-doing Python has become a big 1,000 monster. I am refactoring the whole thing, they say 3rd time is a charm... I have now chosen to neatly organize stuff in places according to function, refactor +100 lines functions in smaller, readable ones, etc...

**To the point: where should I place my imports?**
Where would it make it more efficient / right from a coding-quality perspective?

Say my structure is like this:

```
myPetMonsterProject/
│
├── main.py
├── mod1.py
├── mod2.py
└── mod3.py
```

Now let's say all 4 modules, including `main`, use `numpy`, should I do it in all modules? I guess I should otherwise it won´t run, right? But would that create any unnecessary inefficiency?

Say `Pandas` is used by `mod1` and `mod2`, `import` in both?

Now, say `os` is used only by mod3? Or should I do all `imports` at `main.py`?

If this is a stupid question and there´s simply a link I could not find googling, please let me know!

Comment: " should I do it in all modules?" **Yes**  "I guess I should otherwise it won´t run, right? But would that create any unnecessary inefficiency?" **No**, no it won't.

Comment: You should import the libraries you are using in a module at the top of the module.

Comment: shouldn't you just add a ```__init__.py```

Comment: never mind misunderstood the question import everything to main.py